# Union arrays from all object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Lets say I have an object:

```
    let obj={
         hash1:{
            images:[img1,img2....]
         }
         hash2:{
            images:[img100,img200....]
         }  
         hash3:{
             images:[img1000,img2000....]
         }
      ...       
}
```

I want to union all those arrays in one array.
I understand that I can use next code:

```
let unionArray=[];

Object.values(obj).forEach((item)=>{
unionArray=unionArray.concat(item.images)
});
```

Are there more elegant way to do such task e.g with some framework or in one line coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array reduction will do pretty nicely here:

```
let union = Object.values(obj).reduce((c, i) => c.concat(i.images), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` on `Object.keys()` and ES6 spread syntax.

```js
let obj = {"hash1":{"images":["img1","img2"]},"hash2":{"images":["img100","img200"]},"hash3":{"images":["img1000","img2000"]}}

var arr = [].concat(...Object.keys(obj).map(e => obj[e].images));
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `Array#map`.

```
const union = [].concat(...Object.values(obj).map(v => v.images));
```